# How to change the url of static file when I use the Parameters in path

Tags: go, go-gin

```
router.Static("/static", config.STATIC_PATH)
router.LoadHTMLGlob(config.TEMPLATE_PATH+"/*")
router.GET("/user:uname",handlers.Index )
```

The href of css file will become "/user/static/css/fontawesome.css",gin add "user"
on all the href of css, js in index.html,how to avoid that?

Comment: Could you write a little bit more? I have no idea what your problem is and what your target is.

Comment: @apxp I think the problem is that static assets are getting routed through the router.GET line not the router.Static line. Is this right @dawenxi?

Comment: It sounds like you may just need to add a `<base>` to your HTML, but with no code to look at it's hard to say for certain.